# Error on trying merge two forms (entites) in Symfony 2

Tags: symfony, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I was trying merge two entities (user and student) to create a single form, below are my orm files

```
Ens\JobeetBundle\Entity\User:
  type: entity
  table: abc_user
  id:
    user_id:       { type: integer, generator: { strategy: AUTO } }
  fields:

    username: { type: string, length: 255, notnull: true, unique: true }
    email:    { type: string, length: 255, notnull: true, unique: true }
    password: { type: string, length: 255, notnull: true }
    enabled:  { type: boolean }
  oneToOne:
    student:
      targetEntity: Ens\JobeetBundle\Entity\Student
      mappedBy: user

Ens\JobeetBundle\Entity\Student:
  type: entity
  table: abc_student
  id:
    student_id: { type: integer, generator: { strategy: AUTO } }        
  fields:
    first_name: { type: string, length: 255, notnull: true }
    middle_name: { type: string, length: 255 }
    last_name: { type: string, length: 255, notnull: true }
  oneToOne:
    user:
      targetEntity: Ens\JobeetBundle\Entity\User
      joinColumn:
        name: user_id
        referencedColumnName: user_id
```

Creating entities and updating scheme is working fine,

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities EnsJobeetBundle

php app/console doctrine:database:update --force
```

But when trying to generate crud

```
php app/console generate:doctrine:crud --entity=EnsJobeetBundle:Student
```

I am ending up with the following error,

```
[RuntimeException]

The CRUD generator expects the entity object has a primary key field named "id" with a getId() method.
```

Does any know how to get rid of this? how to merge two forms in Symfony 2?

Any help will be much appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

This is because the CRUD generator does not support id that are customised, like student_id etc...
See [code](https://github.com/sensio/SensioGeneratorBundle/blob/master/Generator/DoctrineCrudGenerator.php#L69-71). As indicated below, if id is not in your entity, you will get a Runtime Exception.

```
//....
if (!in_array('id', $metadata->identifier)) 
{
    throw new \RuntimeException('The CRUD generator expects the entity object has a primary key field named "id" with a getId() method.');
}
//....
```

You will have to rename your custom id in your models:

**User:**

```
protected $id;

public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}
```

**Student:**

```
protected $id;

public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}
```